# How can "cin" mess a loop up?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I wrote a program that let you insert ***n*** names and then print those names on the the screen. When i set ***n*** to a fixed value, the program runs fine.  However, when i add a cin command `cin>>n` , it seems that the program skips the first loop. I noticed that whenever i use `cin` the problem comes up. I think when i press enter at the cin command that enter tell the first loop that
`n[0]=''`(maybe). Can you guys help me fix this. Sorry for my English.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{int n;cin>>n;//the root of the problem(i think)
    char **p = new char *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        *(p + i) = new char[255];
    } //make a 2 dimensional array of strings

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        char n[255] = "";
        cout << "insert names no."<<i+1<<": ";
        gets(n); 
        strcpy(p[i], n);//insert the names into the array of strings
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << p[i] << endl; //print the names
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `cin` to read an int doesn’t consume the newline you send so the next read consumes it

Comment: You should check the value of `n` just after the cin to verify it is a valid value. Aslo check that the cin >> n succeeded,

Comment: I can forgive your English, but your C++ needs to be improved ;)

Comment: [gets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/) - *"The most recent revision of the C standard (2011) has definitively removed this function from its specification. The function is deprecated in C++ (as of 2011 standard, which follows C99+TC3)."*

Comment: `char n` Why do you reuse `n`?

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
cin >> n;
```

Will read all the digits you have input, but **not** the line-feed character that follows. This single line-feed character will then be picked up by your call to `gets()`. This eventually result in the first name to be empty.

You can:

- Either use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> instead of <kbd>Return</kbd> at your terminal prompt to send the value without sending a line-feed
- Or skip the white-space by using `cin >> n >> ws`. In that case you must also  `#include <iomanip>`.

Also, you'd better not mix iostream and stdio functions and you should use `std::string` instead of C strings.